# Old expected value or summation notation from the early 20th century

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, notation, math-history

I've tried looking everywhere online for this but I have turned up absolutely nothing.

In William Gosset's original paper "The Probable Error of a Mean" where he constructs his now famous t-distribution, there's this notation for what seems to be a summation. The pattern of the usage of the notation indicates that he may be writing the identity that in modern terms can be written $Var[X] = E[X^2] - E[X]^2$. Past that point, the notation leaves me grasping at straws. You can see it below.

[image: Student's summation notation.]

All right, so what's up with this? I'm guessing this is some very archaic math form for summation - I mean it just has to be. Past the second equal sign, I'm just confused, again mainly because I don't recognize his notation. Why doesn't he index his variables of summation with a dummy variable (if that's even what he's trying to do?) And what's with the lack of comma separating the sample values, should that be expected from these older papers?

[Here's a link to the paper in its entirety.](https://www.york.ac.uk/depts/maths/histstat/student.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

In more familiar terms, by the formula for the square of a sum,

$$\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2-\left(\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\right)^2=\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2-\frac1{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2-\frac2{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=i+1}^n x_ix_j.$$

The notation $S(x_1x_2)$ is questionable, because it doesn't clearly shows that the summation indexes do not cover the whole range $[1,n]\times[1,n]$.

Comment: couldn't you correct this by changing the upper limit of summation? i've seen it done before by other people when squaring sums.

Comment: @sqrtpapi2001: ooops, my bad, when the factor $2$ is pulled out, the triangular domain *must* be used. Now fixed.

Comment: what is the "triangular domain"? That sounds interesting.

Comment: @sqrtpapi2001: come on, check the shape of the domains.

Comment: when you say "domain" i imagine you're talking about that cartesian product you have there that you're saying is the (ambiguous) range of all index of summation values for i and j. what makes it triangular? also what area of math is this coming from, i find that quite interesting.

Comment: @sqrtpapi2001: this is elementary. Draw it.

Answer (score 1):

Try reading $S(x_1)$ as $\sum\limits_i x_i$, then $S(x_1^2)$ as $\sum\limits_i x_i^2$ and $S(x_1 x_2)$ as $\sum\limits_{i,j} x_ix_j$

Comment: And what about $S(x_1x_2)$ ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust - edited

Comment: Why do you think he opted to skip writing the indices? Is there a relevant technical reason?

Comment: @sqrtpapi2001 It was the style of the time, and probably easier to typeset. I came across it when [commenting on the preface of Fisher's 1925 Theory of Statistical Estimation](http://www.se16.info/hgb/Fisher_prefatory_proposition.pdf), where he said "Given any series of proper fractions $P_1,P_2,\ldots,P_s$, such that $S(P_k) = 1$" to mean that they added up to $1$.

Comment: I don't quite agree with your retranscription of $S(x_1x_2)$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust - I see that from the postscript in your answer.  That ambiguity may be a disadvantage of this abbreviated notation

Comment: @Henry: you kept the ambiguity, and if I were to interpret $\sum_{i,j}$, I would choose the wrong interpretation.

Comment: @YvesDaoust $S(x_1x_2)$ is clearly $\sum_{i>j}x_ix_j$ as further down in the paper he says "$S(x_1^2x_2^2)$ has $\frac12n(n-1)$ terms".

Comment: @A.Γ.: I know that $i>j$ (or equivalently $i<j$, see my answer ) !!! But this is not "embedded" in the notation. $\sum_{i,j}$ is nothing but clear and without context you would be mistaken.